# Blur effect sublayer does not disappear with xib

Tags: ios, swift, xib, blur

I'm implementing a blur effect on a view (with Swift 4.1, Xcode 9.3) with the following code:

**myXib** - loads the nib view and adds the blur subview

```
func setup() {
    // load xib view
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("myXib", owner: self, options: nil)
    self.view.frame = bounds
    self.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    self.addSubview(self.view)

    // create blur effect
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = blurView.bounds
    blurView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    blurView.insertSubview(blurEffectView, at: 0)
    isBlurShowing = true
}
```

I use a simple toggle button that calls show() or hide() functions.

```
func hide() {
    blurView.isHidden = true
    blurView.alpha = 0
    isBlurShowing = false
}

func show() {
    blurView.isHidden = false
    blurView.alpha = 1
    isBlurShowing = true
}
```

The sample myXib looks like this:

[image]

where the grey area is the blurView (set to Clear Color normally, only set to grey here for descriptive purposes.)

For a view (orange) under the blurView but **inside** the Xib the hide() function works correctly but for the view (blue) **under** the Xib view the blur effect remains.

With blur on (.isHidden = false, .alpha = 1)

[image: blur on]

with blur off ((.isHidden = true, .alpha = 0)

[image]

The blur effect is less when turned off but it is still present. 
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured this out.

The issue is that I was creating a second blur layer at 0 because I was calling it also in an init function by having:

```
override init (frame : CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

required init? (coder aDecoder : NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}
```

Once I removed these the code functioned correctly.